# Get all requests urls of a page in Python

Tags: python, networking

Is there anyway to get all requested urls of a page? For example, when I visit a site, browsers make multiple network requests to for example, html, css and other files from the server that are necessary to display the page. I want to get all those assets urls using Python. Basically, I want to get all the urls like from the screenshot below. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

PS: I want to do this with scripting to automate the task. I know that I can accomplish this kind of task using Wireshark which I cannot automate.

[image]

Comment: The first thing to realise is that the answer to the question "what files are necessary to display the page" can depend what browser you're running. For starters, any JavaScript on the page might display completely different things according to browser name, version, or other aspects of the JavaScript environment. You can't perfectly imitate a particular browser, although you can use e.g. selenium to drive one.

Comment: @SteveJessop I don't know if you understand my question. I don't need to know what files are necessary to display the page. I just want to get any urls that get further requested for example when I visit, www.google.com.

Comment: The "urls that get further requested for example when I visit" a URL also can depend what browser you visit it with (in fact I'm not sure how that's different from what I said). My point is that I could write a page that requests image A when loaded in Firefox, or image B when loaded in Chrome. What do you want: the URL of A or the URL of B? The only way Python can know for sure what IE does when it visits a page is to watch IE doing it.

Comment: @SteveJessop Either one of them. Any urls that gets requested.

Comment: Well, if you don't care at all which browser then just always return an empty list (or only the URL of the html page itself), since there exists a browser (Lynx) that won't load any images, CSS or javascript when you visit a page because it doesn't support any of those things ;-) Or do you mean that you're going to manually visit the URL yourself using the browser of your choice, and you want Python to tell you afterwards what additional resources were loaded?

Comment: @SteveJessop I am looking for something like this[1], but I want to do it via terminal using Python.

1. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/iaiioopjkcekapmldfgbebdclcnpgnlo

Comment: If you carefully read what @SteveJessop was saying, **you can't do that for any arbitrary page unless you are actually using a browser.** JavaScript can do very different things depending on the browser, and its version, and what platform it's running on, and what the window width is, etc. It can make AJAX calls and request different resources all day long. The thing is, any moderately complex page will do different things for different users in different situations and that often includes requesting different resources. Things are different now than they were in 1996 when you could do this.

Answer (score 0):

For others interested: the next snippet, which I got from [a post from pythoncode](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/extract-web-page-script-and-css-files-in-python), worked for me.

I am sure it has some limitations as the ones described above (different browsers, different paths, etc., making this hack non-general), but it may save someone's day.

```
# get the CSS files
css_files = []

for css in soup.find_all("link"):
    if css.attrs.get("href"):
        # if the link tag has the 'href' attribute
        css_url = urljoin(url, css.attrs.get("href"))
        css_files.append(css_url)
print(css_files) # list of URLs of the files called
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use gtk + webkit2. Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tokland/f2f4a0b05fde8a48dbc48a28e70f831d) for a full working example.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit2

def on_resource(webview, resource, request):
    print(request.get_uri())
    return True

def load(url):
    window = Gtk.Window()
    window.set_default_size(800, 600)
    window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

    webview = WebKit2.WebView()
    webview.connect("resource-load-started", on_resource)
    webview.load_uri(url)

    window.add(webview)
    window.show_all()

    Gtk.main()
```